# Visual Studio Code Enter not working in Debug Console

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I'm following the Rust book, and using Visual Studio Code. I have arrived at the part where you program a guessing game. Given this code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Guess the number!");

    println!("Please input your guess.");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
}
```

I expect to type a number in the debug console, afterwards it will be printed to the debug console. This has worked once. But in repeated tries, it appears my enter press is just being ignored. When I run the executable in Powershell it works as intended. Below is what I'm seeing in the VSC debug console. What happened?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how the rust tooling behaves. But might it be, that the output is mirrored to `Debug Console` but that the input is still expected in the `Terminal` tab?

Comment: I checked, and no. The debug console always expects the input, the terminal is not showing any activity, or option to enter numbers.